# Redirect feature phone users to another site

Tags: redirect, smartphone, browser-detection

I have a website that works well on all tablets, mobiles and desktops. However when users access the site via a feature phone like a nokia asha or something similar the site doesn't work well at all. What's the best way to redirect users of these types of devices to a basic version of the website?

I've had a look at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ but it detects all types of mobiles as a mobile. Is there a way to differentiate between smart phones and feature phones?

Cheers

Shaun

Comment: Thinking about this, I think I'm going to look at sniffing out ios, android, windows and blackberry then assume any other mobiles are feature phones.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to detect touchscreens. If I understand matters/remember correctly, feature phones do not have those. You should be able to redirect such phones with this:

```
if (!('ontouchstart' in window || window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.yourdomain.ext/feature_page.ext';
}
```

Comment: The Nokia Asha series are effectively feature phones with touchscreens.